# how to send the additional parameters in worldpay form?

Tags: php, laravel-5, worldpay

I am getting the response but i have not get the additional parameters that i have added in our form i have added the startDate and expiryDate but i am not getting these keys in response. Plaese hep me how to do that i am using laravel 5.2 framework
here is my code:-

```
<form action="https://secure-test.worldpay.com/wcc/purchase" method="POST" name="worldpayForm" id="worldpayForm">

<input type="hidden" name="testMode" value="100">
<input type="hidden" name="instId" value="myinstid">
<input type="hidden" name="cartId" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="amount" value="1000">
<input type="hidden" name="currency" value="GBP">
//theses are below  my additional parameters
<input type="hidden" name="startDate" value="2017-04-23">
<input type="hidden" name="expiryDate" value="2017-07-23">

<input type=submit value=" Buy This ">
</form>
```

Here is my laravel fuction to get response:

```
public function thanks(){
    $data = $_REQUEST;
    echo '<pre>'; print_r($_REQUEST); die;
}
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: I don't know about lavarel but, what do you get if you do like this :

public function thanks(){
    echo '<pre>'; echo $_POST['startDate']; die;
}

Comment: undefined index startDate :(

Comment: Sorry, I accidentally commented, then had to delete.  Now I feel obligated to reply.  Try this.. function thanks(){
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value){
echo $key.' is '.$value;
}

Comment: Hmm, do you use firefox ? If yes, download tamperdata addon and look if those field are correctly send when you click on submit

Comment: i am using google chrome

Comment: still not getting startDate in response @Vbudo

Comment: Try changing the name from 'startDate' to something else.  I've had issues with php thinking values are reserved words... just something to try.  Are you getting 'expiryDate?'

Comment: no  i have not get any my additional  parameter even i test with input type text

Comment: So all other inputs are showing when you call the function?

Comment: you need quotes here type="submit"

Comment: yes these are defaults provided by worldpay like instid,cartid, amount,currency but not getting my added paarameters

Comment: yes i changed with quotes but still same issue

Comment: i found the solution @Vbudo and thanks you are trying to help me

Comment: So... what was it?  Was it the function? Out of scope? What?

Comment: i have just download one pdf with brief description and they tell how to send custom parameters.. look at my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally Find the solution of my own after seraching 
Here i have to do only this :-

```
<input type="hidden" name="M_startDate" value="2017-04-23">
the additional parameter name should be like this
```

Hope it help for other in future.

Comment: yes @Vbudo now i am getting response with M_startDate